# Java - private inner class public member

Tags: java, class, nested, private, member

how does the access level modifier change the behavior of a **member** inside an inner private class?
I have this code

```
class Main {
    private static class Inner {
        private static int a = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Inner.a);
    }
}
```

I can access the attribute "a" from the outer class either it's access level is public or private (and this is already weird for me).
The question is: if the **attribute** were "**public static int**", what were the **difference** (considering that the Inner class is private so inaccessible from the extern of the "Main" class)?

To recap

- The attribute is private: I can access it from Main but not from outside Main (because Inner is private)
- The attribute is public: I can still access it from Main but not from outside Main (because Inner is private)

I can see no difference

Comment: You are right, since `Inner` is private, it can be accessed only from within `Main`. Even if `a` is public, but `Inner` is private and cannot be accessed from a particular place, attribute of `a` would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inner` is private, it can be accessed only from within `Main`. Even if `a` is public, but `Inner` is private and cannot be accessed from a particular place, attribute of `a` would be irrelevant.

```
class Main {
    private static class Inner {
        public static int a = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Inner.a);
    }
}
```

When you run ,

```
1
```

Whenever `Inner` is static in the same class,(`Main`), `Inner` (and all its members) are always accessible from anywhere in the `Main` class. It is private outside of `Main` Class. If I were to access

```
Main main = new Main();
main.Inner; // Compilation Failure. Inner is not accessible
// Technically I would never do new Main(), but to illustrate I am doing so.
```

Or a more sensible example of the same

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(SomeClass.Inner);
    }
}

class SomeClass{
    private static class Inner {
        public static int a = 1;
    }

}
```

To illustrate the difference of making `a` private or public, consider the following two examples

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(SomeClass.Inner.a);
    }
}

class SomeClass{
    public static class Inner {
        private static int a = 1;  // If a is private, it produces an error above
      //public static int a = 1; // This would not be an error
    }
}
```

So in your particular case, as long as it is in same class `Main`, it is irrelevant, but if it is outside as next example, it would matter.

Comment: Ok, but wat's the difference of making public the attribute of a private inner class?

Comment: What's the difference of making public the attribute when Inner is private?

Comment: When `Inner` is in same class as `Main` : `public` or `private` does not matter as long as you are in `Main` Class.
http://shar.es/TjDcx

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your `Inner` class as a class-level attribute. Making it private prevents access to it *outside* of the class. Since it's an inner class, the inner class's variables belong to the outer class and are thus accessible to the outer class, regardless of the access modifiers.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html